# Divide slice on slice of the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have

```
In [0]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]})
In [1]: df
Out[2]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     5
```

What I need is to divide `df[1:]` on `df[:-1]` and get a dataframe as a result, like this:

```
Out[3]: 
   col1    col2
0   2.0    1.3333333333333333
1   1.5    1.25
```

But of course I'm getting

```
Out[3]: 
   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   1.0
2   NaN   NaN
```

I've tried using `iloc` for slicing, but got the same result. I'm aware of `df.values`, but I need a dataframe as a result. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide numpy array created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[1:].values / df[:-1].values, columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
   col1      col2
0   2.0  1.333333
1   1.5  1.250000
```

Or set same indices in both `DataFrames`:

```
df1 = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True).div(df[:-1].reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
a = df[1:]
b = df[:-1]
b.index = a.index
df1 = a / b
```

---

```
df2 = df[1:]
df1 = df2.div(df[:-1].set_index(df2.index))

print (df1)
   col1      col2
1   2.0  1.333333
2   1.5  1.250000
```

Comment: @mr_bulrathi - Hmmm, I think StackOverflow is super, because many answerers, so if get nice question always get nice answer :) And there is many cool answerers, not only me. But often are offline or are busy ...